# $a \in \mathbb{Z}$,$(a^{n-1}\equiv 1 (mod~n) $ and $\forall q|n-1$, $q$ is prime, $a^q\not\equiv 1 (mod~n)$ then $ n$ is a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

Consider an integer $n \geq  2$  verifying:
$$ \exists a \in \mathbb{Z}, (a^{n-1} \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\  n) \text{ and }\forall q|n-1, q\text { is prime numbre }, a^q\not\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\ n).$$
**Show that $ n$ is a prime number.**

Let $m$ be the order of $\bar{a}$ in the group of invertibles of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. We will show that $m = n-1$. Suppose $m < n-1$. As $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\  n)$, $m | n-1$ and therefore there exists a prime number $q$ dividing $n-1$ such that $m | \frac{n-1}{q}$. This implies that $a^{\frac{n-1}{q}} \equiv 1 (\textrm{mod}\  n)$. According to this test. Can I conclude a contradiction with the assumptions?

Comment: The conditions tell you that $(\mathbb Z/n)^\times$ is cyclic of order $n-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample

Let $n=65$, then the only value of $q$ is $2$.

Let $a=8$, then $8^2\ne 1$ (mod $65$) but $8^{64}= 1$ (mod $65$).

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong as stated, see S. Dolan’s answer.

We can correct this however, and make it into something called Pocklington’s criterion:

If $\exists a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \mod n$ and $\forall q|n-1,$ $q$ prime, $a^{\frac{n-1}{q}}\not\equiv 1\mod n$, then $n$ is prime.

*Notice that the power of $a$ is $\frac{n-1}{q}$, not $q$.*

In fact, this is biconditional. I would give a proof here, but there are various sources online.